# Extracting value in REST controller

Tags: forms

Can you help me in below scenario?

This is  GET method URL- http://localhost:9090/abc/deleteConfiguration?54

Now I need to extract 54 value in REST Controller, but I am unable to get this value in this method

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/deleteConfiguration", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView deleteConfiguration() {

}
```

Comment: The part after "?", you must follow the rule name=value. You can create your url like this "/deleteConfiguration/54".

Comment: this is my dynamic requests

Comment: function deleteCommnad() {
   var configurationidvalue=  $('#configurationid').text();
   alert("configurationidvalue:::"+configurationidvalue);
      $.ajax(
      {
       url: 'http://localhost:9090/smart-light-nokia/deleteConfiguration',
       data: 
        configurationidvalue = configurationidvalue
       ,
      
       type: 'GET',
        success: function(data){
               alert(data);
             }
       }); 
   
  }

Comment: data: configurationidvalue = configurationidvalue, this part is wrong. try this data: { configurationidvalue: configurationidvalue  }. It will generate the url like this deleteConfiguration?configurationidvalue=54. Then in your action, just put parameter, deleteConfiguration(int configurationidvalue)

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/, you should read the document more carefully before asking the question.

Comment: Thanks so much for this help.now It is working fine.. Again thanks & your saved my job...:)